# Flask behind gunicorn and nginx sending http instead of https to azure ad resulting in AADSTS50011

Tags: nginx, flask, azure-active-directory, gunicorn, azure-ad-msal

This follows another question from last week only now I have more information.
I downloaded the MS graph sample app here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp.

I entered the following for the app.config.py file:

```
import os

b2c_tenant = "tenant"
signupsignin_user_flow = "B2C_1_signupsignin1"
editprofile_user_flow = "B2C_1_profileediting1"

resetpassword_user_flow = "B2C_1_passwordreset1"  # Note: Legacy setting.
    # If you are using the new
    # "Recommended user flow" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions),
    # you can remove the resetpassword_user_flow and the B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY settings from this file.

authority_template = "https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/{user_flow}"

CLIENT_ID = "client_id_hidden" # Application (client) ID of app registration

CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret_hidden" # Placeholder - for use ONLY during testing.
# In a production app, we recommend you use a more secure method of storing your secret,
# like Azure Key Vault. Or, use an environment variable as described in Flask's documentation:
# https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/#configuring-from-environment-variables
# CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("CLIENT_SECRET")
# if not CLIENT_SECRET:
#     raise ValueError("Need to define CLIENT_SECRET environment variable")

AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(
    tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=signupsignin_user_flow)
B2C_PROFILE_AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(
    tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=editprofile_user_flow)

B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY = authority_template.format(
    tenant=b2c_tenant, user_flow=resetpassword_user_flow)
    # If you are using the new
    # "Recommended user flow" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions),
    # you can remove the resetpassword_user_flow and the B2C_RESET_PASSWORD_AUTHORITY settings from this file.

REDIRECT_PATH = "/getAToken"  # Used for forming an absolute URL to your redirect URI.
                              # The absolute URL must match the redirect URI you set
                              # in the app's registration in the Azure portal.

# This is the API resource endpoint
ENDPOINT = '' # Application ID URI of app registration in Azure portal

# These are the scopes you've exposed in the web API app registration in the Azure portal
SCOPE = []  # Example with two exposed scopes: ["demo.read", "demo.write"]

SESSION_TYPE = "filesystem"  # Specifies the token cache should be stored in server-side session
```

Next I landed it on a centos 7 node: toolbox01.mycompany.com. Then I setup gunicorn and a wsgi file to run it:

```
from app import app as application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run()
```

Next I registered a service in /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=runguni
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/home/myuser/ms-identity-python-webapp-master
Environment="PATH=/home/myuser/ms-identity-python-webapp-master/msflaskenv/bin
ExecStart=/home/myuser/ms-identity-python-webapp-master/msflaskenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind 0.0.0.0 -m 000 wsgi

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally I setup nginx to read the site:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name myserver.mycompany.com;

        return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
    }
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name myserver.mycompany.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/selfsigned.key;

        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;
        location / {
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                    proxy_redirect off;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

Lastly I registered my application in Azure and registered the server under Authentication as https://myserver.mycompany.com. I also included https://myserver.mycompany.com/getAToken.

The problem is that when I run the site, and click on "sign in", the url being sent is: http://myserver.mycompany.com. Not https://myserver.mycompany.com. So I get the AADSTS50011 error. Here's the URL as it is in my browser:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<removed tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client id>?&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.mycompany.com%2FgetAtoken&scope=User.ReadBasic.All+offline_access+openid+profile&state=SpOcEwhzdGBXxMsv&code_challenge=<challenge hash>&code_challenge_method=S256&nonce=<challenge hash>
```

Can anyone see what I've configured wrong? All requests should be https but they're clearly not.

Answer (score 1):

After digging through the gunicorn documents again I found the section of the deploy page I've missed a dozen times: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html

In nginx.conf, I need to add the following to my location block for port 443:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

This forces all calls from Gunicorn to use https.